# Opening a local file in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How can I open a file that is stored on my hard drive without using a local server or something like that in JavaScript? 
I am not taking about something like a HTML `input` where the user selects a file to be opened. I have seen this answer that looks promising but doesn't work: 
[How to read a local text file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file)

Comment: I don't think it is possible unless the user actually uploads something using the input element as you said. I mean it would be quite bad if you enter a website and all of a sudden without you uploading anything the script on the website crawls around your file system and stuff...

Comment: thare is a non-standard API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_and_Directory_Entries_API

or you can use a `node.js` where you are not limited by browser' security reasons